# TS2540: Cannot assign to 'matricule' because it is a read-only property

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers

I want to display a tab with variables from the Json file,
I created a service file and linked to component.ts, and in this component I created a method ( get data ) to get these variables, but got an error like it was a readonly property

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference `this.matricule` (a `matricule` variable in your current class) but have only defined a getter (`get matricule(): Mat[]`)

The `matricule` variable is outside of the scope of your class and cannot be accessed with `this`.